# How can I set up an a SQLite memory database to improve PHPUnit test speeds?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to speed up a functional Drupal test.
Given a test...

```php
...
  public function the_front_page_loads_for_anonymous_users() {
    $this->config('system.site')
      ->set('page.front', '/node')
      ->save(TRUE);

    $this->drupalGet('<front>');

    $assert = $this->assertSession();
    $assert->pageTextContains('Welcome to Drupal');
    $assert->pageTextContains('No front page content has been created yet.');
  }
```

This test runs really slow against my database ... 2+ mins.

If I use a test sqlite database, it drops to around 1.6 mins
`<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlite://localhost/logs/test.sqlite"/>`

If I use a in-memory database, `<env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="sqlite://localhost/:memory:"/>`, Drupal detects no database and runs `install.php`

How can I set up an `sqlite memory` database to improve test speeds?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, we use [sqlite://localhost/dev/shm/test.sqlite](https://github.com/localgovdrupal/drupal-container/blob/596e0bc03241c240d1f7bf05ea5c53ba55a233ac/run-tests.sh#L31) where [/dev/shm is memory mapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems)

Comment: OK ... unfortunately I'm on a work PC, which runs Win10 and I have been unable to get hardware virtualization working which prevents me from using WSL2.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your approach though. I appreciate it. Hopefully, next upgrade cycle, I can implment a Docker or WSL2 solution. I'll be sure your try out your method. :)